How to add JSON object inside script tag in NextJS
I'm trying to set some configuration values within a Cookiebot initialisation script tag in a NextJS project.
The documentation specifies that I can set vendor properties by passing in a JSON object inside the script tag as shown below (taken from https://support.cookiebot.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007652694-Cookiebot-CMP-and-the-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework-TCF#h_01EH49KGTMFNNX4CPJEYJKTZ19):
<script id="CookiebotConfiguration" type="application/json" data-cookieconsent="ignore">
  {
    "Frameworks": {
      "IABTCF2": {
        "AllowedVendors": [2, 6, 8],
        "AllowedGoogleACVendors": [],
        "AllowedPurposes": [1, 2],
        "AllowedSpecialPurposes": [],
        "AllowedFeatures": [1],
        "AllowedSpecialFeatures": [1],
        "VendorRestrictions": [
          {
            "VendorId": 2,
            "DisallowPurposes": [2, 3, 4]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>

When I try to do this in my NextJS app however, I get an error '}' expected.
This is my implementation:
     <Script id="Cookiebot" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js" data-cbid="REMOVED" data-blockingmode="auto">
            {
               "Frameworks": {
                   "IABTCF2": {
                       "AllowedVendors": [2, 6, 8],
                       "AllowedGoogleACVendors": [],
                       "AllowedPurposes": [1, 2],
                       "AllowedSpecialPurposes": [],
                       "AllowedFeatures": [1],
                       "AllowedSpecialFeatures": [1],
                        "VendorRestrictions": [
                           {
                               "VendorId": 2,
                               "DisallowPurposes": [2, 3, 4]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
           }
            </Script>

How do I set this JSON object properly without seeing the error?
Thanks,
Ben
EDIT:
As pointed out in the comment, I do need to separate these tags, the syntax error does remain however. The implementation is now:
    <Script id="CookiebotConfiguration" type="application/json" data-cookieconsent="ignore">
        {
            "Frameworks": {
                "IABTCF2": {
                    "AllowedVendors": [2, 6, 8],
                    "AllowedGoogleACVendors": [],
                    "AllowedPurposes": [1, 2],
                    "AllowedSpecialPurposes": [],
                    "AllowedFeatures": [1],
                    "AllowedSpecialFeatures": [1],
                    "VendorRestrictions": [
                        {
                            "VendorId": 2,
                            "DisallowPurposes": [2, 3, 4]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    </Script>

The syntax error below remains, however:
'}' expected.

Your implementation has a src attribute.  A script can only have a src attribute or internal content but you have both.  Try two separate script tags - one to load the code from the src and the other containing the json config.

Thanks @James - this doesn't fix the syntax error but you're absolutely right about this. I've updated my post to reflect this update.

Depending on how the cookiebot script is being loaded, you may need to change the strategy to beforeInteractive: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/script#beforeinteractive

@James you are correct in that the browser will not parse/execute the content of the script tag, when a src is given. The script that gets loaded via src however can then go and read & parse the text content of the script element itself. This is a very common pattern for these types of external widgets. (And if this is the way the provider of the widget says it should be done, then it is very unlikely that dividing this into two separate script elements, would even work to begin with.)

That’s interesting @CBroe, are you sure that’s the case here?  Their site says to add the config tag “before the standard Cookiebot tag“.

@James no, it does not appear to be the case here. This "inline" style of configuration has the advantage, that the script can use document.currentScript to access its own script element, and then easily get the text content. Relying on mere order of script elements could probably prove tricky in some scenarios, so here I'm guessing they simply use the ID CookiebotConfiguration to find the relevant script element.

You're getting a syntax error because you're passing invalid JavaScript inside the {} block in your JSX.
Two things to keep in mind:

Anything inside {} blocks inside of JSX is considered JavaScript. In your example you're passing:

"Frameworks": {
    "IABTCF2": {
        "AllowedVendors": [2, 6, 8],
        "AllowedGoogleACVendors": [],
        "AllowedPurposes": [1, 2],
        "AllowedSpecialPurposes": [],
        "AllowedFeatures": [1],
        "AllowedSpecialFeatures": [1],
        "VendorRestrictions": [
            {
                "VendorId": 2,
                "DisallowPurposes": [2, 3, 4]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Which is not valid JavaScript (notice that this whole thing is not an object.

Objects are not valid React children. Even if you had passed the correct object inside you'd be getting an error nonetheless.


In your case, you should probably pass this JSON as a string:
<Script id="CookiebotConfiguration" type="application/json" data-cookieconsent="ignore">
    {`
        {
            "Frameworks": {
                "IABTCF2": {
                    "AllowedVendors": [2, 6, 8],
                    "AllowedGoogleACVendors": [],
                    "AllowedPurposes": [1, 2],
                    "AllowedSpecialPurposes": [],
                    "AllowedFeatures": [1],
                    "AllowedSpecialFeatures": [1],
                    "VendorRestrictions": [
                        {
                            "VendorId": 2,
                            "DisallowPurposes": [2, 3, 4]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    `}
</Script>

This works because Next.js's Script tag supports inline scripts.
